# Error while installing ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Below is the error, while trying to installing Babel package through Node.JS
[image]

Comment: This is not reproducable. This is most likely a problem at your side of the connection. Make sure you have an internet connection and you don't have firewalls disabling NPM.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to connection problem, 
Make sure you're connected to any high speed network.